# combine common value based on some key in list of tuple

Tags: python, dictionary

e.g

```
data = [ (item1, ('1-jan' ,45)) , (item2, ('21-jan',65)), (item1, ('21-jan',48))]
```

I like something like:

```
result = [ (item1, [('1-jan' ,45),('21-jan',48)]), (item2, [('21-jan',65)])]
```

to be precise I need final outcome

```
result = { item1: ('1-jan':45,'21-jan':48)), item2: ('21-jan':65)]
```

Comment: [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: whats with the `:` in your values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [*dict.setdefault()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to easily create groupings in a dictionary:

```
>>> data = [ ('item1', ('1-jan' ,45)) , ('item2', ('21-jan',65)), ('item1', ('21-jan',48))]
>>> result = {}
>>> for k, v in data:
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

>>> result
{'item2': [('21-jan', 65)], 'item1': [('1-jan', 45), ('21-jan', 48)]}
```

You can also use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) to achieve the same end.

Comment: Thanks @raymondHettinger, Though I figured it out but your answer is neater. My solution was ---
result = {} ---
for k, v in deco:---
    result.setdefault(k, []).append(v) ---
    try: ---
        result[k] += v ---
     except KeyError: ---
         result[k] = v ---

Answer (score 1):

If @Raymond's `setdefault()` doesn't work for you, try a `defaultdict(list)` object:

### source

```
data = [ ("item1", ('1-jan' ,45)) , ("item2", ('21-jan',65)), ("item1", ('21-jan',48))]

from collections import defaultdict
out = defaultdict(list)
for key,value in data:
    out[key].append(value)

print out
```

### output

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'item2': [('21-jan', 65)], 'item1': [('1-jan', 45), ('21-jan', 48)]})
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not as simple as iterating through each value and adding it to a dictionary.  You must check to make sure that the key (item1, item2) are not in the dictionary first.  If they are, you must append the value to the existing key.

Here you go:

```
data = [ ('item1', ('1-jan' ,45)) , ('item2', ('21-jan',65)), ('item1', ('21-jan',48))]

dataDict = {}

for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i][0] not in dataDict:
        dataDict[data[i][0]] = data[i][1]
    else:
        dataDict[data[i][0]] += data[i][1]
```

As the above users have commented, you can use default dictionaries to make life more simple.